# sql query update row if contains variable from array

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a table

```
id / product_id / var / active / price
```

the var column contains three variables separated by `:`

```
e.g. (37:48:80)
```

i want to change the price column to a set value if var contains the right options.

i.e.

```
33:38:57 through to 80 would = 450 
33:39:57 through to 80 would = 0 
33:40:57 through to 80 would = 0 
33:41:57 through to 80 would = 450
```

i would like to pass the first variable an array of the second variable and if matched update price

my very bad sql would look like:

```
   UPDATE 'price' = 450 
   WHERE 'var' = 33:array(38,41 etc):array(57,58 etc)
```

i know thats really wrong but thought may help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you have three values in one field in your database in the first place?

Comment: its how open cart does it very annoyoing

Comment: Show us some code. With what input do you expect what output.

Comment: i have no code i just want to update the table through phpmyadmin

Comment: Need more information and code. 33:38:57 through to 80 doesn't really make sense

Comment: my very bad sql would be something like     UPDATE 'price'= 450 where 'var' = 33:array(38,41,etc):array(57,58 etc)

Comment: You need to explain what `33:38:57 through to 80 would = 450` means. Be more specific about what results you expect and how you'd expect to calculate them. If you don't have any working code, pseudo-code will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get the `through to 80` but I get the idea of your query (I guess...). I kinda hate regular expressions but they seem to be the right tool to solve this. Give this a try:

```
update t set price = 450
where var regexp '^33:(38|41):(57|58)$'
```